# How to use an async geolocation value with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, geolocation, angularjs-ng-repeat

JS noob here.

I'm trying to build an app (with Angular-Meteor) that lists restaurants around and one of my views is supposed to show, for each restaurant, the distance between your current location and that restaurant. I'm having issues to perform the calculation for each restaurant and then show that value in the view.

With my current code, the top of the page loads, then the function (distanceToPlace) I'm calling gets called for every place then loading is complete and finally I can see the elements with the correct distance value.

There are multiple problems:

- The geolocation API gets called more than once per restaurant, I can't figure out why (I have 50 restaurants in the db, sometimes I see my console log check print 2000+ times)
- Even if it was called only once per restaurant, it would be really inefficient. There should be a way to call it just once when the page loads and then just do the distance calculation with that data for each restaurant. Even better, my whole app should have some kind of global variable containing the user's location (refreshed every X seconds) that I could access from any page.

Additionally I would like to be able to sort the restaurants by distance after the calculations have been done, but I have no clue how to go about this :(

Here is the JS (inside the controller):

```js
        var userLng = '';
        var userLat = '';
        this.loaded = false;
        var that = this;

        //Calculate the distance with coordinates
        function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2) {
            var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
            var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
            var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
            var a =
            Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
            ;
            var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            var d = R * c; // Distance in km
            return d;
        }

        //Calculation sub-formula
        function deg2rad(deg) {
            return deg * (Math.PI/180)
        }

        //Find user's location then start the distance calculation
        this.distanceToPlace = function(placeLng, placeLat) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                userLng = Math.round(position.coords.longitude * 1000000) / 1000000;
                userLat = Math.round(position.coords.latitude * 1000000) / 1000000;
                that.loaded = true;
                console.log('Done');
                return Math.round(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(userLng, userLat, placeLng, placeLat) * 1000);
            });
        };
```

And here's the view:

```html
<md-content flex ng-show="placeSearch.loaded">
  <md-card ng-repeat="place in placeSearch.places | eventDayFilter:placeSearch.eventDay | placeAreaFilter:placeSearch.area | eventTimeFilter:placeSearch.eventTime:placeSearch.eventDay | orderBy:placeSearch.sort">
    <md-card-title>
      <md-card-title-media>
        <div class="md-media-md card-media">
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/611558188744372225/VoCVrXWX.png">
        </div>
      </md-card-title-media>
      <md-card-title-text>
        <span class="md-subhead" ui-sref="placeDetails({ placeId: place._id, lastPage: 'search' })">
                        {{place.name}}
                    </span>
        <small>{{place.events[placeSearch.eventDay].begin}}h-{{place.events[placeSearch.eventDay].end}}h:</small>
        <span class="md-body-1">{{place.events[placeSearch.eventDay].description}}</span>
        <span flex></span>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between end">
          <span class="md-caption">
                            <md-icon md-svg-icon="action:ic_room_24px"></md-icon>
                            <span ng-if="distance=placeSearch.distanceToPlace(place.address.lon, place.address.lat)">{{distance}} m</span>
          </span>
          <md-icon class="icon-fav" md-svg-icon="action:ic_favorite_border_24px"></md-icon>
        </div>
      </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
  </md-card>
</md-content>
```

I use "ng-if" there but I'm not quite sure if it's the right way to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't understanding how angular digest cycles work. Approach is all wrong. Only thing you want to pass to view is actual values. All the distance calcs should be initialized in controller...not from view. Loop over your data in controller after you get user position once

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this problem:

1. I would create a publication that returns a cursor of restaurants
2. The publication would have a single parameter, an object with the current coordinates of the user
3. I would `_.throttle()` that publication so that it doesn't run any faster than once every N seconds (in case the user is moving rapidly)
4. I would run the geoquery in the publication because Meteor doesn't support mongodb geoqueries on the client side, only on the server.
5. I'd then subscribe to that publication from the client, passing the user's current position
6. I'd probably still do the distance computations on the client and the sort there, in a helper that returns an array of restaurant objects, with an extra key for the distance.
7. Then your angular code can just deal with displaying the restaurant objects however you wish
8. When you have all the above code working and debugged then you may enjoy a tall one and also remove your js noob badge.

It doesn't make sense to compute the distance in the helper for an individual restaurant since it's a sort key - you want to do it in the helper that returns the whole list/array of restaurants. Also, like you witnessed, the individual helpers run more often than you might expect.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm a bit confused with points 4-5 though. Since the geolocation query is run inside the "Meteor.publish" function, how can I pass the user's current position (calculated by that query) from the client when I subscribe?

Comment: Aren't you getting the current position on the client? If so then you would do `handle = Meteor.subscribe('nearbyRestaurants',myLocation)` on the client and `Meteor.publish('nearbyRestaurants',function(myLocation){})` on the server.